# Display PDF doesn't work with Byte[] attribute, in context Angular, spring and S3 application

Tags: html, angular, spring, byte, aws-s3-client

Good morning,
I use Angular, Spring and AWS S3 for an application in which I display png, jpg, pdf files...
I retrieve an Object from the backend which contains a Byte[], however I want to display a .pdf type file I get this error.

```html
<img width="800px" [src]="'data:image/pdf;base64,'+ ressourceUI.bytes" alt="Image">
```

I also tried with this.

```html
<img width="800px" [src]="'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ ressourceUI.bytes" alt="Image">
```

Its a same problem.

[image]
[image]

Here is the error on the browser side

[image]
How can I fix it